# Running a script on every tty

Tags: linux, shell, tty

I have a shell script that i want to run on every tty

```bsh
echo "Hello!"
```

i tried adding it to my .bashrc but it only works after you login and it executes even if the terminal isnt a tty

Comment: A few years ago I wrote a tool to identify each user and terminal. It doesn't write to _every tty_ as that would (to me) be pointless. Terminals running 'vi', 'watch' and other full screen tools are skipped because it can break the layout. There are a number of similar caveats for scripts that "_i want to run on every tty_" so it would be worth making sure you're more precise and detailed in your requirements/question/issue. (I wonder if you actually mean that you want this text to be displayed each time you start a new interactive shell. But that's not what you've asked.)

Answer (score 0):

A tty doesn't run anything – it's a (virtual) output device that programs (or the kernel) might control to display things.

So, "I want to run something on every tty" cannot exist. Most things occupying a TTY aren't even shells - so you can't run a shell command "in" them.

You probably want to do something to every user session? Then loginctl might be the way to go. Anyway, that warrants asking a **new question** (not just a comment here, and since it significantly differs from what your question is about now, also not an edit to your current question) about what you want to *achieve* by this. "How can I send a message to every user logged in?" or "How can I update the web login token for system XYZ for every user who is logged into a console on my machine" are very good questions, for example!